# Any subset of the rationals is mappable to all the rationals

Tags: sequences-and-series, rational-numbers

I want to prove that there is a bijection between any interval in the rationals and all the rationals. I'll try to prove a special case and I'm hoping to know if this proof is correct. This is not a homework problem, it is merely a curiosity. I'm not so experienced in math proofs.

I need to prove a bijection exists between any enumeration of all rationals in $(0,1]$ and any enumeration of the rationals in $(0,M]$.

If $s_n$ is an enumeration of the set of all rational numbers in the interval $(0,M]$ where $M$ is a rational number, then:

I am able to define $u_n = s_n/M$ with the property that $0 < u_n \le $. $u_n$ is an enumeration of all the rationals between $0$ and $M$ because if there were any empty space $w$, where $0 < w \le 1$ and $\forall n, u_n \ne w$ it would imply that $Mw$ is not in the set $s_n$ which is a contradiction.

Moreover the interval $(0,1]$ is wholly mappable onto any interval $(0,M]$ since any enumeration of $(0,1]$ multiplied by $M$ is a subset of $(0,M]$. Assume there is an empty space $u$ in the interval $(0,M]$. But $u/M \in (0,1]$. So there are no empty spaces.

Since a map exists in both directions a bijection exists between all the rationals and the subset $(0,1]$ from which I am able to prove that if a bijection exists between $A$ and $(0,1]$ and so too for $B$ then a bijection exists between $A$ and $B$.

If this is true I would be very excited.

Comment: Let $\phi: \mathbb N \to (0,1]$ but an enumeration and $\psi: \mathbb N \to (0, M]$ be an enumeration.  Just define $f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ via $f(k) = \psi^{-1}(M\cdot \phi (k))$.  That is if $(0,1] = q_1,q_2,.....$ and $(0,M] = p_1, p_2,....$ then we can map $k\to q_k \to Mq_k = p_j \to j$.

Comment: It is trivially false that there is a bijection between *any* *subset* of the rationals and all the rationals. For an extreme example, the set containing just zero is a subset of the rationals, and this plainly can't be bijectively mapped to all the rationals! You want to be talking about *intervals*, not *subsets*.

Comment: yea my bad. I should have said intervals. you're right.

Comment: Nitpickery: you've shown that any two _finite_ intervals are equivalent (roughly), but you haven't shown that a finite interval is equivalent to $(0,\infty)$ or $(-\infty, \infty)$. Those mappings can also be done, but they're a little more complicated.

Comment: It might be easier to simply prove any infinite subset of a countable set is countable.  Then you don't *have* to map anything to anything.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki no you are right to be nit-picky. Thank you for pointing that out. I was not sure whether saying it holds for any finite mapping is equivalent to saying it is true for an infinite interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your proof is that if $M$ is itself not a rational number, then $s_n/M$ will not be a rational number.

What you can do instead is note that the rationals in $(0,1]$ and the rationals in $(0,M]$ are both countably infinite, so there are enumerations $(q_n)_n$ and $(r_n)_n$ enumerating them respectively. Then the map sending $q_n$ to $r_n$ for each $n$ is a bijection between the two sets of rationals in question.

Comment: You can in fact *explicitly* construct enumerations of both sets (*i.e.*, it's not just that you know they exist), which gives you an explicit bijection between the two sets.